# How to handle long running tasks in reconciliation loop

Tags: go, kubernetes-operator

I am writing a Kubernetes operator and dealing with a peculiar situation of handling long-running tasks from the reconcile loop.

I have the following situation:

```
func (r *ProvMyAppReconciler) Reconcile(req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    // _ = context.Background()
    _ = r.Log.WithValues("Instance.Namespace", req.NamespacedName)

    // your logic here
    var i int32
    var j int32
    var yappMyAppSpex myAppingv1alpha1.MyAppSpec
    var result *ctrl.Result
    var msg string
    var requeueFlag bool
    runFlag = false


    <<<<< Instance prov logic>>>

    // =============================== Check Deletion TimeStamp========
    // Check if the MyAppOMyApp instance is marked to be deleted, which is
    // // indicated by the deletion timestamp being set.

    // <<<<<<<Deleteion and finalizer logic is here>>>>>>>>
    

    // ================================ MyApp Setup ===================
    if len(instance.Spec.MyApp) > 0 {
            for i = 0; i < int32(len(instance.Spec.MyApp)); i++ {
                    yappMyAppSpex = instance.Spec.MyApp[i]
                    if !yappMyAppSpex.setRemove {
                            result, err = r.provisionStatefulSet(instance, prepareStatefulSetForMyApp(instance, yappMyAppSpex), "TYPE=TELEAPP")
                            if err != nil {
                                    return *result, err
                            } else {
                                    _, err = r.addMyApp(yappMyAppSpex.Name)    <<< This takes lot of time and if I do any operation on a CR resource , it is not cptured by K8s as operator is busy in running this job in foreground.>>>>
                                    if err != nil {
                                            requeueFlag = true
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }


    if runFlag {
            return ctrl.Result{Requeue: true, RequeueAfter: 30 * time.Second}, nil
    }
    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
```

}

I am trying to understand what is the best way to handle the above situation? Do I need to use channels and run them in the background? The main issue here is that I have to run some configuration which is taking a lot of time and causing the K8s operator not to handle other updates that are done on CR.

Comment: I have a similar problem running a custom loop task with operator. Have you found a proper way to handle this problem？

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend is making good use of the resource status. It's important that consumers of the operator know that the operator has acknowledged the changes and is acting on it.

Then, I would recommend revisiting the API definitions - is this the right API to be using? i.e. can you split this up into more than one controller (or API)?

A simple example: in a restaurant it's not a good idea if the cook is also the waiter because you want customers to know they are being taken care of but cooking could take a long time. It's better for customers to have a waiter that takes the order, marks the order status accordingly, and then hands it to the cook(s) to execute on (this could be another API only used between cook and waiter).

In your example above you could add an API for a single app instance. The main controller would only be responsible for applying that API for each of the instances declared in the top level API (which doesn't take long). The worker controller would respond to the creation of that single-app-instance API and execute on it. This still would take time for the worker but visibility and UX would improve.